# Failure opening rule instance pega

Tags: pega

I am trying to open one section but I am getting below error

Failure opening the Rule Instance
Unable to open instance - Possible causes may be

1. Rule may no longer exist.
2. Availability of the rule may be set to No/Draft, Blocked or Withdrawn.
3. Circumstance of the rule may be preventing access.
4. Current date is not within the date range specified in the rule.
5. Access group or role may not have the appropriate privileges to open the rule.
   Error: Fail
   Time:Thu Mar 02 20:52:07 EST 2023
   Operator: KANU
   Node:localhost
   Systemega 8.7.0

Answer (score 0):

You can go into the search box, introduce the name of your rule and click in the dropdown arrow to see if it is available in other versions, withdrawn... You can also change the search from "My Current Application" to "All Applications", just in case. Of course you ought to have rights in the ruleset to actually open open it [image: Search Screen]